# Minor layout inaccuracy: Text offset to SVG image of button in watched tags sidebar-widget

Tags: bug, design, tag-watching

When looking at the 'watched tags' sidebar-widget accross the SE-network

[image]

it catches the eye that (even without those two beautiful free-hand circles ;) )

[image]

The widget-header-text is aligned with the SVG image, but in the button below the text is vertically set off by around 0.15em compared to the SVG image (eye).

I fiddled around a bit and got an appealing result:

[image]

by changing the line-height of the class `s-btn` from

```
line-height: 1.15384615;
```

to

```
line-height: 1.3;
```

which now gives a more consistent look and feel to the layout of this widget.

But since the class `s-btn` is used on various other places in the markup I suggest to add alterations either to the class `js-show-add-watched` or to add a new and unique identifier.

I am using Google Chrome version 70.0.3538.110

You may now crucify me as a pedant ;)

EDIT: I deleted the original post on MSO so there's no dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `6-8 days` later the minor layout inaccuracy has been solved by the lightning-fast development team behind the SE-network:

[image]

Thanks for making the world a little bit more aligned ;)